# How to put the address of the array into a variable

Tags: c++

How can I put the address of the array into a variable?

```
char * str1 = "Hello";
int add = 0;
```

Now I want to put the address of the array into `add`.
I know I can print out the address of the array by the following way:

```
printf("Address = %p", str1);
```

But, I want to store the address in the variable.

Comment: str1 is actually an address

Comment: If you are on a 64-bit platform, a normal `int` won't suffice as it's only 32 bits and a pointer (which technically is an address) is 64 bits.

Comment: always use `size_t` when you really want to convert an address to an integer. However, this is not recommended. If your algorithm requires the conversion of addresses (pointers) to integers, then this is suggestive of a **design problem**.

Comment: @Walter: even `size_t` is not guaranteed to be big enough (although it is in practice). `uintptr_t` has the required property, but is not guaranteed to exist (although it does in practice, admittedly on C++03 you might have to get a third-party `stdint.h` suitable for your platform). It's a bit of a mess.

Comment: @Steve formally you're correct and in C++11 one should use `uintptr_t`. **BUT** I bet many codes would break if `size_t` couldn't hold an address ...

Comment: @Walter: Many codes would break if a lot of things not guaranteed by the standard didn't happen, for starters because a lot of people write non-portable code. Formally is the *best kind* of correct to be! In practice all it means is that whatever type you use, you have a slight worry about whether it could fail on some peculiar implementation. Ideally that worry should prompt the programmer to wonder whether converting a pointer to an integer is really sensible, rather than crippling them with doubt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to store a memory address in a variable, the correct way is to type the variable as `std::intptr_t` or `std::uintptr_t`. That is because these types are *guaranteed* large enough to hold any memory address:

```
char * str1 = "Hello";
uintptr_t p = (uintptr_t)str1;
```

Apart from that, note that the value of `str1` is already a memory address (it points to `H`) albeit a different one from the value of `&str1` (which points to `str1`).

Comment: ... and hence `str1` is the address of the array, and `&str1` is not the address of the array. It's the address of one variable (perhaps one of many) that holds the address of the array.

Comment: "...these types are guaranteed..." - if they exist, but they're optional content from `<cstdint>`, so may not be there at all (18.4.1).

Comment: @SteveJessop: Mea culpa, misread the question. Fixed and thank you for the correction.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: True. However I 'll let the answer stand because how to define them yourself is a proper question in its own right.

Comment: "char str1[] = "Hello";
char * str2 = &str1[0];
uintptr_t p = (uintptr_t) str2;
std::cout << std::hex << p << std::endl;
p = (uintptr_t) &str1[1];
std::cout << std::hex << p << std::endl;
p = (uintptr_t) &str1[0];
std::cout << std::hex << p << std::endl;"

This is what i achieve. They give the same result. :D
Thanks Jon and Steve.

Jon, in your answer, str1 is the address of the array, however, &str1 is the not the address of the array. It is the address of the pointer of the array.

Thanks again mates.

Comment: @Tony: ideally, the standard would define that *if* the implementation has a signed/unsigned integer type that can hold any address, *then* `intptr_t`/`uintptr_t` are required to exist. Then you could just happily use `uintptr_t`, and on implementations where what you want to do is impossible, your code won't compile. Unfortunately, as you say it's completely optional, so in fact the code fails to compile either if what you want to do is impossible, or if the implementer is a lazy so-and-so who hasn't bothered defining `uintptr_t`.

Answer (score 3):

Turning a pointer into a number requires reinterpretation:

```
add = reinterpret_cast<int>(str1);
```

But there are all kinds of problems associated with this approach:

- If sizeof(int) < sizeof(char*) then part of the pointer is lost, you won't be able to restore it.
- Some optimizations might turn your code invalid due to unexpected aliasing.

If you need a variable which can hold pointers *or* integers, it would be better to use a union instead.

Comment: what is the problem with aliasing, if I may ask?

Comment: No guarantees that this is according to the standards, but I understand things this way: Suppose you are passing the int to a function, which turns it back into a char* and changes the content of the string. The compiler might conceivably store a character of the string to a register before the call, and use that cached version after the call returned, thus missing the modification. The optimizer would expect that passing only ints to a function would never affect content of local variables.

Comment: Oh, I see, you're right. However I am not sure if this is strictly aliasing (but in any case something very close to). Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Use `reinterpret_cast` (see 5.2.10/p4):

> 4 A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type large enough to hold it. The mapping function is
>   implementation-defined. [ Note: It is intended to be unsurprising to those who know the addressing structure
>   of the underlying machine. —end note ]

```
static_assert( sizeof( unsigned int ) >= sizeof( &str1[ 0 ] ),  "warning: use a wider type!" );
unsigned int add = reinterpret_cast< unsigned int >( &str1[ 0 ] );
```

Answer (score 1):

From your comment on Jon's accepted answer:

```
char str1[] = "Hello";
char* str2 = &str1[0];
uintptr_t p = (uintptr_t)str2;
std::cout << std::hex << p << std::endl;
p = (uintptr_t)&str1[1];
std::cout << std::hex << p << std::endl;
p = (uintptr_t)&str1[0];
std::cout << std::hex << p << std::endl;
```

This implies your objective is to be able to stream the pointer value in a readable format.  The Standard provides for this in an implementation-defined fashion as follows:

```
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(const void* p);
```

So, perhaps what you really want is satisfied by the C++ style or (concise but less self-doncumenting and compiler-checked) C-style code below:

```
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(str1) << '\n';
std::cout << (void*)str1 << '\n';
```

(But, if you specifically want a numeric versions, or to ensure it's displayed in hex with no leading 0x or whatever else an implementation may decide upon, then you're back to Jon's suggestion or your own (possibly compile-time checked) logic to find a big enough integral type.